# d3.js Tooltip positioning not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with a d3 scatterplot and I want my tooltip to appear beside a dot when I mouse over that dot. I know this is very simple but I don't know where I have gone wrong! This is the relevant code.It throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of null
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful as I am new to d3! Thanks in advance.

```
// add the tooltip area to the webpage
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.style("opacity", 0);

function mouseHandler (d) {

            d3.json("connection3.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error,data) {

                var authorList = ""
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    authorList = authorList + d.AUTHOR;
                    console.log(authorList);
                    })

                tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", .9);
                tooltip.html(authorList)
                    .style("left",(d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");                            
            })
            }
```

css:

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 28px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: lightsteelblue;
```

}

Comment: Can you reproduce it in codepen or jsfiddle? It will be easy to debug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lines:

```
  .style("left",(d3.event.pageX) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
```

would work well if they were directly inside the mousehandler function. However, they are within a callback function for `d3.json`, so it would explain why `d3.event` is no longer defined.

So try to save the values of `pageX` and `pageY`  to local variables before calling d3.json.

```
  function mouseHandler (d) {
        var pageX=d3.event.pageX;
        var pageY=d3.event.pageY;


        d3.json("connection3.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error,data) {

            var authorList = ""
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                authorList = authorList + d.AUTHOR;
                console.log(authorList);
                })

            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", .9);
            tooltip.html(authorList)
                .style("left",(pageX) + "px")
                .style("top", (pageY - 28) + "px");                            
        })
        }
```